# Can these vaccine records and test tool kit satisfy the requirements for entering Hong Kong?

Tags: covid-19, hong-kong

Do you have to meet any [COVID-related requirements](https://www.coronavirus.gov.hk/eng/inbound-travel.html) if you are arriving at Hong Kong International Airport and intend to take the high-speed train into mainland China?

> Non-Hong Kong residents aged 12 or above on the day of arrival at Hong Kong: Fulfilled vaccination requirement;

> Persons aged four or above on the day of arrival at Hong Kong: Rapid Antigen Test (RAT) conducted within 24 hours or PCR-based nucleic acid test conducted within 48 hours prior to the scheduled time of departure (for arrivals via the airport) or before arrival at Hong Kong (for arrivals via other boundary control points), and obtained negative result; and

> Retain the photo showing the RAT result or the PCR test report for 90 days

Where...

> Fully vaccinated means the suggested dosage has been administered in accordance with the “List of COVID-19 Vaccines Recognised for Specified Purposes” https://www.coronavirus.gov.hk/pdf/list_of_recognised_covid19_vaccines.pdf of a COVID-19 vaccination course at least 14 days prior to the day of departure for Hong Kong.

Is this standard CDC card sufficient to meet the requirements for proving one's vaccination status?

[image]

Can a test in this BinaxNow kit be satisfactory for conducting the RAT testing?

[image]

Comment: I've updated the images and text slightly, please feel free to rollback if you think it made the post worse.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the COVID related requirements that have to be met

Yes, as you will be entering Hong Kong to get to the train station

> Are these vaccine records satisfactory for the fully vaccinated requirements?

Yes, it's Pfizer-BioNTech which is in the list

And you have more than the required 2 doses